# How to remove the background image from a UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

In my app I am having `UITableView` in one of my `UIView`.I added a background image for all cells. My problem is , when I select a particular cell,I want to change the background image of that particular cell alone and all the other cells should have a old background image.
How can i do this. Please share your ideas.

Here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MenuItem3"]];

    cell.backgroundView = bgView;



    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14];



    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.text = [arrayValue objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    cell.selectionStyle =  UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: just use table reload data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Need to reload all your table just reload PreviousInxed like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }


    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bck.png"]];

    UITableViewCell *celld = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:table.indexPathForSelectedRow];
    celld.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"raj_star.png"]];

    return cell;
}

NSIndexPath *perviouseIndexPathaf;

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (perviouseIndexPathaf)
    {
        [table reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:perviouseIndexPathaf]
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"raj_star.png"]];
    perviouseIndexPathaf = indexPath;

}
```

Comment: I tried ur code.It provided almost what I want.But initially it crashed my app.Then I took off that if part and executed.It worked.The background image is changing but  when I come to that table view,the cell is unselected and looks like other cell(unselected).Is it possible to keep the new bg until another cell selected.Thank you

Comment: just give me crash report... i checked it and then upload my answer

Comment: This is the error am getting:"2012-12-10 16:59:16.995 project[1491:1d903] +[InfoViewController section]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1f7c10
2012-12-10 16:59:16.996 project[1491:1d903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[InfoViewController section]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1f7c10'
*** First throw call stack:
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception"

Comment: Anyhow without that if statement itself,its working for me.Can I know what for that if statement u r using?

Comment: check more updated answer...in previous answer when we are scrolling table then the image of selected cell in disappear ,

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if (tableView.tag == 3)// We are checking if it's the desire tableview. If you have only one tableview then you can remove this if.
        {
            [tableView reloadData];
            UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.backgroundView = bgView; // Here set the particular image u want.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually I tried this before itself.It works, but the problem is when the other cell is selected, this cell's image should be set to old one.Instead the new image is still there.Its shows like many cells are selected.Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *objCustomCell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NewImage"]];
    objCustomCell.backgroundView = bgView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in addition to your code, add the following code.

```
UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SelectedMenuItem3"]];

cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgView;
```

For more info, check the documentation for [UITableViewCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s `selectedBackgroundView`